# Rails - Variable from controller not being passed to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I can get an object in the view from the "new" method but cannot get it from another method from controller. Why?

So, I have this in the routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'horarios/new'=> 'horarios#new'
    get 'horarios/newprofessor'=> 'horarios#newprofessor'
end
```

And this in the horarios_controller.rb:

```
class HorariosController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @horario = Horario.new
        @teste = "it prints!"
    end

    def newprofessor
        @teste = "it prints!"
    end
 end
```

And put this in both views (new.html.erb and newprofessor.html.erb):

```
<% raise @teste.inspect %>
```

The "new" view gives me the object, but the "newprofessor" view says that it's nil. Why is that? Thank you!

--EDIT
(adding all code)
horarios_controller.rb

```
class HorariosController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @horario = Horario.new
        @teste = "it prints!"
    end

    def addhorarioprofessor
        puts params[:Sex10]
        if params[:Sex10] == "1"
            puts "foi"
            @horario = Horario.where(:hora_inicio => "10:00", :dia_semana => "Sexta-feira").first
            @horario.update_attributes(:professor_id => 6)
            @horario.save
        end
        redirect_to '/'
    end 

    def create
        @horario = Horario.new(horario_params)
        if @horario.save
            redirect_to '/'
        else
            render 'new'    
        end
    end

    private
    def horario_params
        params.require(:horario).permit(:dia_semana, :hora_inicio, :hora_fim, :professor_id)
    end

    def index
        @horarios = Horario.all
    end

    def newprofessor
        @horarios_preenchidos = Hash.new
        @horarios = Horario.new
        @teste = "it prints!"
        for horario in @horarios
            if horario.professor_id != nil
                @tah_preenchido = true
            else
                @tah_preenchido = false
            end
            @horarios_preenchidos[horario.dia_semana+"_"+horario.hora_inicio] = @tah_preenchido
        end 
    end    
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'professors' => 'professors#index'
    get 'professors/new' => 'professors#new'
    get 'horarios/new'=> 'horarios#new'
    get 'horarios/newprofessor'=> 'horarios#newprofessor'
    post 'professors' => 'professors#create'    
    post 'horarios'=> 'horarios#create'
    post 'horarios/newprofessor' => 'horarios#addhorarioprofessor'
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Horarios#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/horarios/new.html.erb</p>
<% raise @teste.inspect %>
<%= form_for(@horario) do |f| %>  
  <div class="field"> 
      <%= f.label :dia_semana %><br> 
      <%= f.text_area :dia_semana %><br>
    <%= f.label :hora_inicio %>
    <%= f.text_area :hora_inicio %>
      <%= f.label :hora_fim %>
    <%= f.text_area :hora_fim %>

  </div> 
  <div class="actions"> 
    <%= f.submit "Create" %> 
  </div> 
<% end %>
```

newprofessor.html.erb:

```
<h1>Horarios#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/horarios/new.html.erb</p>
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
<% raise @teste.inspect %>


<%= form_tag({ :method => :post }) do  %> 
<%= text_field :Horario, :attribute_name %><br>
<table>
    <th>
        <tr>Segunda</tr>
        <tr>Terça</tr>
        <tr>Quarta</tr>
        <tr>Quinta</tr>
        <tr>Sexta</tr>
    </th>
  <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag 'segunda-feira_05:00', '1', false, disabled: true %> 05:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Ter5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qua5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qui5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Sex5 %> 0x:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :Seg6 %> 06:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Ter5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qua5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qui5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Sex5 %> 0x:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :Seg7 %> 07:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Ter5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qua5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qui5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Sex5 %> 0x:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :Seg8 %> 08:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Ter5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qua5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qui5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Sex5 %> 0x:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :Seg9 %> 09:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Ter5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qua5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qui5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Sex5 %> 0x:00</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :Seg10 %> 10:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Ter5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qua5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qui5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Sex5 %> 0x:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :Seg11 %> 11:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Ter5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qua5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qui5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Sex5 %> 0x:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :Seg12 %> 12:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Ter5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qua5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Qui5 %> 0x:00</td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag :Sex5 %> 0x:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>

  <div class="actions"> 
      <%= submit_tag "Save" %> 
  </div> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Not enough code. There's something you don't show us.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry, I thought it wasn't relevant! Edited :)

Comment: You don't use `@teste` in `newprofessor.html.erb`

Answer (score 1):

When I put the "newprofessor" method as the first one in the controller ir works (and I have no idea why it works).

```
class HorariosController < ApplicationController
    def newprofessor
        @horarios_preenchidos = Hash.new
        @horarios = Horario.all
        @teste = "it prints!"
        for horario in @horarios
            if horario.professor_id != nil
                @tah_preenchido = true
            else
                @tah_preenchido = false
            end
            @horarios_preenchidos[horario.dia_semana+"_"+horario.hora_inicio] = @tah_preenchido
        end
    end   

    def new
        @horario = Horario.new
        @teste = "it prints!"
    end

    def addhorarioprofessor
        puts params[:Sex10]
        if params[:Sex10] == "1"
            puts "foi"
            @horario = Horario.where(:hora_inicio => "10:00", :dia_semana => "Sexta-feira").first
            @horario.update_attributes(:professor_id => 6)
            @horario.save
        end
        redirect_to '/'
    end 

    def create
        @horario = Horario.new(horario_params)
        if @horario.save
            redirect_to '/'
        else
            render 'new'    
        end
    end

    private
    def horario_params
        params.require(:horario).permit(:dia_semana, :hora_inicio, :hora_fim, :professor_id)
    end

    def index
        @horarios = Horario.all
    end


end
```

Comment: Perhaps, because it's not in private section anymore.